# Error compiling E-ACSL FRAMA-C

Tags: frama-c, acsl

I am new to Frama-C framework and I am trying to do some contract testing with C programs. I intend to use E-ACSL plugin for this, and I tried a test program to see how it works, but I get some compilation errors. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int x = 0;
  /*@ assert x == 1;*/
  /*@ assert x == 0;*/
  return 0;
}
```

Then, here is the Frama-C annotated code:

```
/* Generated by Frama-C */
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
struct __e_acsl_mpz_struct {
   int _mp_alloc ;
   int _mp_size ;
   unsigned long *_mp_d ;
};
typedef struct __e_acsl_mpz_struct __e_acsl_mpz_struct;
typedef __e_acsl_mpz_struct ( __attribute__((__FC_BUILTIN__)) __e_acsl_mpz_t)[1];
/*@ ghost extern int __e_acsl_init; */

/*@ ghost extern int __e_acsl_internal_heap; */

extern size_t __e_acsl_heap_allocation_size;

/*@
predicate diffSize{L1, L2}(ℤ i) =
  \at(__e_acsl_heap_allocation_size,L1) -
  \at(__e_acsl_heap_allocation_size,L2) ≡ i;

*/
int main(void)
{
  int __retres;
  int x = 0;
  /*@ assert x ≡ 1; */ ;
  /*@ assert x ≡ 0; */ ;
  __retres = 0;
  return __retres;
}
```

Finally, I try to compile it with [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) and the flags the [manual](https://frama-c.com/download/e-acsl/e-acsl-manual.pdf) indicates (page 13) but I get the following errors (and warnings):

```
$ gcc monitored_second.c -o monitored_second -leacsl -leacsl-gmp -leacsl -jemalloc -lpthread -lm

monitored_second.c:10:1: warning: ‘__FC_BUILTIN__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
 typedef __e_acsl_mpz_struct ( __attribute__((__FC_BUILTIN__)) __e_acsl_mpz_t)[1];

monitored_second.c:18:55: warning: ‘__FC_BUILTIN__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
                                                   int line);
                                                   ^
monitored_second.c:25:60: warning: ‘__FC_BUILTIN__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
                                                        size_t ptr_size);
                                                        ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leacsl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leacsl-jemalloc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've also removed the "-rtl-bittree" label because it returns another error.

Frama-C version is the latest: Sulfur-20171101
Got any idea of what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: The warnings are explained on page 13.

Comment: I think you may need to pass a `-L` linker flag telling the compiler where to find the libraries you want to link. Look for a directory containing a file called `libeacsl.so` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you should have a script called `e-acsl-gcc.sh` installed in the same directory as `frama-c` binary, that can take care of calling `gcc` with appropriate options. Its basic usage is documented in section 2.2 of the manual, and `man e-acsl-gcc.sh` gives more details on the options that can be used. In short, you should be able to type

```
e-acsl-gcc.sh -c \
  --oexec-eacsl=first_monitored \
  --oexec=first \
  --ocode=first_monitored.i \
  first.i
```

to obtain

- an executable `first_monitored` with the e-acsl instrumentation
- an executable `first` with the original program
- a source file `first_monitored.i` with the e-acsl generated C code

**Edit** Looking at the linking command used by the script, I'd say that the command line proposed earlier in the manual is out of date (in particular, it refers to `eacsl-jemalloc` whereas `e-acsl-gcc.sh` seems to prefer `eacsl-dlmalloc`), which could probably be reported as a bug at https://bts.frama-c.com